# Loop Through Array and Echo Next Event

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have events stored in mysql that I retrieve with php. I retrieve the month, day, and year, then I add it to an array. Is there a way to loop through that array and grab the next upcoming event?

```
$array = [''];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM events") or die ("couldn't fetch query");

// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $date = $row['eMonth'] . "-" . $row['eDay'] . "-" . $row['eYear'];
    array_push($array, $date);
}
```

Comment: order by date when you select from your table

Comment: That would definitely make it easier but I have I have columns in my table that is month, day, and year. So there really isn't a way to sort it by date.

Comment: @TylerMiddleton `order by year,month,day`.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 0):

create a date column for each event and use this query to select next 3 events from current date

```
SELECT *
    FROM EVENTS
    WHERE event_date >= CURDATE() ORDER BY event_date ASC  LIMIT 3;
```